# java program doesn't recognizes subordinate classes "package input does not exist"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to understand [this demonstration example](https://fedorahosted.org/released/javapackages/doc/#_example_java_project). Only the class `HelloWorld` is given, therefore I have to implement the `Input` and the `Output` class myself.

i understand the error message: java can't find the `Input.java` and the `Output.java` file, while importing them. therefore the file `HelloWorld.class` is not correctly built. But i don't understand the reason why this happens. I guess, I've made a small mistake in the directory structure of the filesystem or the imports - but i can't spot it. Where is my error?

I've read also [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382593/how-to-compile-java-package-structures-using-javac?rq=1) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140512/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files-when-there-are-java-files-in-other-packages?rq=1), but that also doesn't work.

---

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld;

import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input;
import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output.Output;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("What is your name?: ");
        String reply = Input.getInput();
        Output.output(reply);
    }
}
```

---

**Input.java**

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    public static String getInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String returnVal = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();

        return returnVal;
    }

}
```

---

**Output.java**

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld;

public class Output {

    public static void output(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

---

```
$ find
.
./src
./src/org
./src/org/fedoraproject
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output/Output.class
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output/Output.java
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.class
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.java
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.class
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
```

---

```
$ java -cp src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.class:src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output/Output.class src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.class
Error: Could not find or load main class src.org.fedoraproject.helloworld.HelloWorld.class
```

---

```
$ javac -cp src/ src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java:3: error: cannot access Input
import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input;
                                         ^
  bad source file: src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.java
    file does not contain class org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

---

**Update**:

After changing the package declarations of `Input.java` and `Output.java` to:

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input;
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output;
```

which produces (applying the suggestions in the answers):

```
$ javac -cp src org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java:3: error: package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input does not exist
import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input;
                                         ^
org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java:4: error: package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output does not exist
import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output.Output;
                                          ^
org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        String reply = Input.getInput();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Input
  location: class HelloWorld
org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Output.output(reply);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Output
  location: class HelloWorld
4 errors
```

---

**Last Update**
It worked now, after these commands, executed in the parent folder of `src':

```
$ find -type f
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output/Output.java
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/output/Output.class
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.class
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/input/Input.java
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
./src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.class
~/java-example-project 
$ javac -cp src/ src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
~/java-example-project 
$ java -cp src org.fedoraproject.helloworld.HelloWorld
What is your name?: toogley
toogley
```

Comment: Well yes, you haven't declared a package called `org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input`. Look at your package statements: `package org.fedoraproject.helloworld`. You should also make your source locations match your package declarations, which they don't at the moment.

Comment: Mind you, the error message you're showing suggests your code isn't as described anyway: `import input.Input` - that's not the same as import `org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for both hints.

Comment: I have replicated your project as you have described it, but I am not getting the error. Did you also recompile ```Input``` and ```Output``` after changing the package declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Change package declaration of the `Input`/`Ouput` class:

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input;
```

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output;
```

Since they are in the `input`/`output` folders.

2.) Classpath should be set to the root of all packages, and the main class passed should use the *fully qualified name*:

```
$ java -cp src org.fedoraproject.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Comment: well, after `javac -cp src/ src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorld.java` and `java -cp src src/org/fedoraproject/helloworld/HelloWorl` I get this: `Error: Could not find or load main class src.org.fedoraproject.helloworld.HelloWorld`

Comment: @toogley Could you try with ```./src``` as the classpath or maybe ```src/``` ? I usually do this on windows. But rest assured, [the classpath should be set to the default package, i.e. the root.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: @toogley Oh is just noticed, the ```src/``` should not be in front of the path to the main class. Sorry.

Comment: oh, sorry. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Your `java` invocation is wrong - it should be `java -cp src org.fedoraproject.helloworld.HelloWorld`. You specify the name of a class, not its file system location.

Comment: @JornVernee I addressed that in my updated question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but using ```/``` instead of ```.``` works too. (I just used the word 'path' because it looks like one)

Comment: @JornVernee: It does now, but it didn't used to - and I don't know whether it works universally. It's definitely better to specify the class name, IMO. I would *definitely* make a point of using the class name in its regular form in answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet I usually use ```.``` but I thought ```/``` was the standard/original way. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

the package header for input and output is not correct

you are doing

import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.input.Input;
import org.fedoraproject.helloworld.output.Output;

but input class is in

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
```

and output

```
package org.fedoraproject.helloworld;

public class Output {
```