# Java Class path in different directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to invoke a java class that is not in current directory. Ive set -classpath flag and ensured that the class file is also there in the path. But im getting the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Fileversion
```

Bat file code

```
java -classpath x:/LCMSLatestLibrary/Fileversion/Fileversion.class Fileversion H:\LCMS_Jars\client.jar x:\LCMSLatestLibrary\64bit\client.jar
pause
```

The same works if I cd into x:/LCMSLatestLibrary/Fileversion and execute the above line without -classpath flag. What am I missing?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382593/how-to-compile-java-package-structures-using-javac) is helpful

Comment: I dont have a problem with compilation. That worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set as classpath the jar or directory containing your packages.
In your case (assuming the class Fileversion is in the default package) the command should be:
java -classpath x:/LCMSLatestLibrary/Fileversion Fileversion H:\LCMS_Jars\client.jar x:\LCMSLatestLibrary\64bit\client.jar

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Thanks a lot.