# The declared package "a" does not match the expected package ""

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Having this file schema:

```
folder "a"
        |
        |_____ MyClass.java
```

Where my ".java" file has this code:

```
package a;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");

    }
}
```

I was wondering the reason why I get this error (I'm using visual studio, I say it in case it is related to my error):

```
The declared package "a" does not match the expected package "".
```

I've noticed that sometimes when I reopen my folder It suddenly works, however other times it doesn't.

I don't know why this happens, I believe the reason it's related to visual studio but it goes further of it, since when I try to compile it, as said, sometimes It works, others don't.

Telling me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/MyClass (wrong name: MyClass)
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, you need the "source folder" to be the folder above `a`, not `a` itself, because package names are resolved relative to the source folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
package a;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");

    }
}
```

It depends from where you are referencing the class.  If `a` is a subfolder and you are trying to compile `MyClass.java` from within `a` it won't work (unless you specify the correct folder like `./..` or similar.  Packages are relative to some root folder or other package.

Comment: Do you know any source which explains this "Relative behaviour" of packages more in depth?

Comment: I find this situation can be most troublesome when doing command line compiling with `javac`.   So check out [How to compile java package structures using javac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19382593/1552534) for more information.  This can be related to  most IDE's which have an expected root from which packages start.  In `Eclipse`, that would be the source file `(src)` of the current project.